# Calculating the directional derivative of $ xy^3/(x^3+y^6)$.

Tags: derivatives

$f(x,y)= xy^3/(x^3+y^6)$ if $(x,y)\neq 0$, $f(x,y)=0$  if $(x,y)=0$.

Prove that $f'(0; a)$ exists for every vector $a$. 
I know how to find the directional derivative from limit equation, but don't know how to prove it. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by prove it?

Answer (score 0):

So, you should fix a generic vector $(a_1,a_2) \in\mathbb{R}^2$ and prove that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(0+\epsilon a_1,0+\epsilon a_2)-f(0,0)}{\epsilon}
$$
exists as a real number. Now,
$$
f(0+\epsilon a_1,0+\epsilon a_2)-f(0,0) = \frac{\epsilon a_1 \epsilon^3 a_2^3}{\epsilon^3 a_1^3 + \epsilon^3 a_2^3} = \frac{\epsilon^4 a_1 a_2^3}{\epsilon^3 ( a_1^3 + a_2^3)} = \epsilon \frac{a_1 a_2^3}{ a_1^3 + a_2^3}.
$$
Now divide by $\epsilon$ and you find that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial (a_1,a_2)}(0,0)=\frac{a_1 a_2^3}{ a_1^3 + a_2^3}.
$$
Since $(a_1,a_2) \neq (0,0)$, the limit exists as a real number.